# How to retrieve the text removed by regex sub?

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex expression in Python that is expected to remove all occurences of the word "NOTE." and the following sentence.
How can I do it correctly and also return all sentences being removed that way?

```
import re
text = "NOTE. This is the subsequent sentence to be removed. The weather is good. NOTE. This is another subsequent sentence to be removed. The sky is blue. Note that it's a dummy text."
clean_text = re.sub("NOTE\..*?(?=\.)", "", text)
```

**Expected result:**

clean_text:

```
The weather is good. The sky is blue. Note that it's a dummy text.
```

unique_sentences_removed:

```
["This is the subsequent sentence to be removed.", "This is another subsequent sentence to be removed."]
```

Comment: Did you mean to match TYPE instead of NOTE? `\bTYPE\.\s*([^.]*\.)\s*` See https://regex101.com/r/a3qHaD/1

Comment: Sorry, I meant removing "NOTE" and its subsequent sentence. I updated the post.

Comment: @KellyBundy https://ideone.com/ETXcoW

Comment: @Fluxy Like in 2 steps? https://ideone.com/ETXcoW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stealing [The fourth bird's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75413751/12671057) regex but using [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) so we only need to search once. It returns a list alternating between non-matched and matched parts. Join the former to get the text, and the latter are your removals.

```
import re
 
pattern = r"\bNOTE\.\s*([^.]*\.)\s*"
text = "NOTE. This is the subsequent sentence to be removed. The weather is good. NOTE. This is another subsequent sentence to be removed. The sky is blue. Note that it's a dummy text."
 
parts = re.split(pattern, text)
 
clean_text = ''.join(parts[::2])
print(clean_text)
 
unique_sentences_removed = parts[1::2]
print(unique_sentences_removed)
```

Output:

```
The weather is good. The sky is blue. Note that it's a dummy text.
['This is the subsequent sentence to be removed.', 'This is another subsequent sentence to be removed.']
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/YHlDYM)

Comment: It's all good :-) Nice using split!

Answer (score 2):

One option to remove the NOTE part is to use a pattern what also matches the dot after the next line followed by optional whitespace chars, instead of asserting the dot only.

If you add a capture group to the pattern, you can use re.findall with the same pattern to return the capture group value.

The pattern matches:

- `\bNOTE\.\s*` Match the word `NOTE` followed by `.` and optional whitespace chars
- `([^.]*\.)` Capture group 1, match optional chars other than `.` and then match the `.`
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars

See the matches and the capture group value at this [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/YaggAS/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ETXcoW).

```
import re
 
pattern = r"\bNOTE\.\s*([^.]*\.)\s*"
text = "NOTE. This is the subsequent sentence to be removed. The weather is good. NOTE. This is another subsequent sentence to be removed. The sky is blue. Note that it's a dummy text."
clean_text = re.sub(pattern, "", text)
print(clean_text)
 
unique_sentences_removed = re.findall(pattern, text)
print(unique_sentences_removed)
```

Output

```
The weather is good. The sky is blue. Note that it's a dummy text.
['This is the subsequent sentence to be removed.', 'This is another subsequent sentence to be removed.']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the removed sentences in one pass using a replacement function with a side-effect that saves the removed sentence:

```py
import re

def clean(text):
    removed = []
    def repl(m):
        removed.append(m.group(1))
        return ''
    clean_text = re.sub("NOTE\.\s*(.*?\.)\s*", repl, text)
    return clean_text, removed

text = "NOTE. This is the subsequent sentence to be removed. The weather is good. NOTE. This is another subsequent sentence to be removed. The sky is blue. Note that it's a dummy text."
result, removed = clean(text)
print(result)
print(removed)
```

Output:

```
The weather is good. The sky is blue. Note that it's a dummy text.
['This is the subsequent sentence to be removed.', 'This is another subsequent sentence to be removed.']
```